# what is the difference saving a byte in OutputStream

Tags: java, file, serialization, inputstream, outputstream

Hello I have the next code:

```
package com.jucepho;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Copy{
public Copy(byte[] buffer,int count) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.count = count;
}
private byte[] buffer;
private int count;

public byte[] getBuffer() {
    return buffer;
}
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}

public class ReaderTwo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("ex.docx");
     OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("exBu.docx");
     OutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream("exBu2.docx");
    ArrayList<Copy> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int count;
    while ((count = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
           os.write(buffer, 0, count);
        lista.add(new Copy(buffer,count));
    }

    for(Copy c: lista) {
        os2.write(c.getBuffer(), 0, c.getCount());
    }


}

}
```

I want to read a file more than 5 GB in order to save it. So I saw that I have to read it in this way ([Encrypting a large file with AES using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447037/encrypting-a-large-file-with-aes-using-java))

My question is, why

```
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("exBu.docx");
```

copy the data good, i mean the file is correct but

```
OutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream("exBu2.docx");
```

is not correct, is corrupted or I don't know why if I am doing the same, right? I am saving in my ArrayList the same information so why my file is corrupted. (and yeah I need to save all the information in an Object called Copy as you see because I will use serialization and save it in other HD)

Thank you

Comment: Why on earth would you do it this way? Just add `os2.write(buffer, 0, count)` into your copy loop. Don't save entire files in memory. It wastes both time and space.

Comment: I want to save it in a file and encrypt it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Copy(buffer,count)
```

This doesn't create a new `byte[]`, it just passes the same array over and over into the `Copy` instance; next time you read data into that array, you overwrite the contents of the array in all previous `Copy` instances.

If you want the `Copy` to remain unchanged, copy the buffer:

```
new Copy(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, count), count)
```

(or do it in the constructor: `this.buffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, count);`)

Comment: Oh I see now, very nice explanation.